# Foreign key not updating with primary key?

Tags: php, mysql

These are my  2 tables:

```
customer_details(c_id,c_name,c_vehicleNumber,c_phone,c_email) primary_key(c_id)AUTO INCREMENT and innoDB.
service_initiation(c_id2,si_id,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) primary_key(si_id) AUTO INCREMENT and innoDB
foreign_key(c_id2) references customer_details(c_id) on delete cascade and on update cascade.
```

However,i insert values through a html page to the table service_initiation,using PHP code for feilds si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5 and for c_id2 i use mysql_insert_id/last_insert_id.

Am getting an error saying"error 1452 :cannot add or update a child row: foreign key constaint fails".

```
Below is my php code:
$value1=mysql_insert_id();
$value2=$_POST['si_1'];
$value3=$_POST['si_2'];
$value4=$_POST['si_3'];
$value5=$_POST['si_4'];
$value6=$_POST['si_5'];



$query="insert into service_initiation(c_id,si_id,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) values ('$value1','','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: cascade on update will update fields..

Comment: yes i have given the same, but its not working and showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

> on delete cascade and on delete update.

but this should be

> on delete cascade and on update cascade.

Comment: yes i have given the same, but its not working and showing the same error.

Comment: IS THERE ANY PROBLEM WITH MY PHP CODE?